# mootools setProperty method does not work on iphone, ipad

Tags: javascript, iphone, methods, mootools, href

I want to change anchor tag's href property using mootools [setProperty](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Element%3asetProperty) method

It does work in all browser including chrome and safari but not working on iphone, ipad and android mobile.

e.g. `$('a').setProperty('href', '#');`

also tried simple javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName("my-class")[0].setAttribute("href","#");
```

Above both example works in all browser.

Anyone have idea?

Answer (score 0):

depends on mootools version. `setProperty` got deprecated* AGES ago.

since 1.2, it's `.set('href', '#');`

keep in mind `$('a')` is not 'select all anchors' like in jquery. it's get element with id=a. to select all anchors you'd do `document.getElements('a');` or `$$('a')`

---

* Deprecated by convention, it's still on the prototype

Comment: Sorry, it does not working on iPhone or iPad. It does work only on desktop browsers. I want to set property using mootools or javascript that work on iPhone and iPad

Comment: it works fine on an iphone and ipad. once again, which version of mootools are you using?

Comment: I am using version:"1.4.0.1" latest version. Actually I am using joomla and it loads latest version of mootools. I have enabled the plugin for this

Comment: thats mootools-more. so i assume 1.4.5? then something is wrong, mootools runs fine on ios. u may have conflcting versions - view source and see what gets loaded, or console.log(MooTools)

Comment: you are right it shows 1.4.5 in console but it does not show any conflict error.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff you said setProperty got deprecated, really is it? I can't find anything about in the mootools documentation.

Comment: it's still available on the prototype but not considered API as such as the best practice is to use `.set()` / `.get()` instead as the single points of entry into changing element props or retrieving them. relevant blog posts around mootools 1.2 release: http://mootools.net/blog/2010/06/10/setting-up-elements/ and the beta announcement/explanation, inc getters and setters http://mootools.net/blog/2008/01/16/mootools-12-beta-2/